# series.str.split(expand=True) returns error: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Tags: pandas

I have a series of web addresses, which I want to split them by the first '.'. For example, return 'google', if the web address is 'google.co.uk'

```
d1 = {'id':['1', '2', '3'], 'website':['google.co.uk', 'google.com.au', 'google.com']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = {'id':['4', '5', '6'], 'website':['google.co.jp', 'google.com.tw', 'google.kr']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df_list = [df1, df2]
```

I use enumerate to iterate the dataframe list

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i]['website_segments'] = df['website'].str.split('.', n=1, expand=True)
```

Received error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

Comment: `df_list[i]['website_segments']` is a Series that you're trying to assign, but the RHS is a DataFrame sooooo that's problematic because Series are 1D by definition and you're trying to shove a 2D DataFrame into it.

Comment: The error is in the first part, df_list[i]['website_segments'], where it expects two columns. Just do something like `ndf = df['website'].str.split('.', n=1, expand=True)` and you will have all in a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the website which gives you a list-like data structure. Think `[google, co.uk]`. You just want the first element of that list so:

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i]['website_segments'] = df['website'].str.split('.', n=1, expand=True)[0]
```

Another alternative is to use extract. It is also ~40% faster for your data:

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i]['website_segments'] = df['website'].str.extract('(.*?)\.')
```